# how to conditionally replace string with sed

Tags: sed

Suppose I have following string. I want to replace `<b>2</b> to <b>20</b>` if `<a>2</a>`

```
<start>
     <a>1</a><b>1</b>
     <a>2</a><b>2</b>
        .
        .
     <a>10</a><b>10</b>
     <a>2</a><b>2</b>
</start>
```

New string should look like this

```
<start>
     <a>1</a><b>1</b>
     <a>2</a><b>20</b>
        .
        .
     <a>10</a><b>10</b>
     <a>2</a><b>20</b>
</start>
```

can I do this using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this:

```
sed '/<start>/,/<\/start>/s!\(<a>2</a><b>2\)</b>!\10</b>!' input
```

and relax the expression as required, for example allow spaces in tag `a`:

```
sed '/<start>/,/<\/start>/{/<a>[ ]*2[ ]*<\/a>/s!<b>2<!<b>20<!}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the first occurrence of `<b>2</b>` with `<b>20</b>` in all the lines with `<a>2</a>` invoke:

```
sed '/<a>2<\/a>/s/<b>2<\b>/<b>20<\/b>/' input
```